# C - How to avoid diacritic/accents sensitive issues

Tags: c, diacritics, wchar

I'm creating a tiny program of guessing the capitals of countries. Some of the capitals have accents, cedillas, etc.

Since I have to compare the capital and the text the user guessed, and I don't want an accent to mess up the comparison, I went digging the internet for some way of accomplishing that.

I came across countless solutions to another programming languages however only a couple of results about C.

None of them actually worked with me. Although, I came to conclusion that I'd have to use the wchar.h library to deal with those annoying characters

I made this tiny bit of code (which replaces É with E) just to check this method and against all I read and understand it doesn't work, even printing the wide char string doesn't show diacritic characters. If it worked, I'm sure I could implement this on the capitals' program so I'd appreciate if someone can tell me what's wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<wchar.h>

const wchar_t CAPITAL_ACCUTE_E = L'\u00C9';

int main()
{
    wchar_t wbuff[128];
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    fputws(L"Say something: ", stdout);
    fgetws(wbuff, 128, stdin);
    int n;
    int len = wcslen(wbuff);
    for(n=0;n<len;n++)
        if(wbuff[n] == CAPITAL_ACCUTE_E)
            wbuff[n] = L'E';
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", wbuff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a problematic subject in standard C. First make clarify which input encoding your platform uses, then take appropriate measures.

Comment: As @Olaf said: You need to know the input encoding. Your example works well with  `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in bash ( I C&P your line "which replaces É with E" for the input). You already use `setlocale(3)`, just read the output and act accordingly (the hardest part, if you ask me).

Comment: With `char`, I have used `tolower(toupper(ch))` to fold and fold again letters that are  "alike".  Perhaps a `wchar_t` equivalent?  Maybe `towctrans()`?

Answer (score 2):

An issue you overlooked is that `É` can be represented as

- `É` - [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH ACUTE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c9/index.htm), codepoint U+00C9 (`c3 89` in UTF-8), or
- `É` - [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/45/index.htm) followed by [COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/301/index.htm), codepoints U+0045 U+0301 (`45 cc 81` in UTF-8)

You need to account for this. This can be done by mapping both strings to the [NFD (Normal Form: Decomposed)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence). After that, you can strip away the decomposed combining characters and be left with the `E`, which you then can `strcmp` as usual.

Assuming you've got an UTF-8 encoded `input`, here is how you could do it with [utf8proc](http://julialang.org/utf8proc/):

```
#include <utf8proc.h>

utf8_t *output;
ssize_t len = utf8proc_map((uint8_t*)input, 0, &output, 
                           UTF8PROC_NULLTERM | UTF8PROC_STABLE |
                           UTF8PROC_STRIPMARK | UTF8PROC_DECOMPOSE |
                           UTF8PROC_CASEFOLD
                          );
```

This would turn all of `É`, `É` and `E` to a plain `e`.